# The list of official Chinese names for common vegetables

Tags: food

Common vegetables list:

1. Kale
2. Water cress
3. Collards/collard greens
4. Brussels sprouts
5. Leeks
6. Artichokes

Other vegetables are, of course, welcomed. The more the merrier.

UPDATED:
Yes, i am aware that all these can be found via online translation or some other sources. But the point is to treat this post as some kind of master list or quick list, in which we have all the names in one place. That way, i will be easier for other people who are looking for the same information, since, you know, they are now collected under one post.

Comment: These items could all be found in Wikipedia, Google Translate and many online dictionaries. And I don't see any legit question in this post

Comment: There is no "official name" for everyday use. The names used in biology is another story and would be different from what is used in everyday life.

Comment: I'm going to leave this open for now, but this is far too broad - perhaps you could tighten it up a bit somehow?

Comment: almost all questions at this site can be answered by looking up online dictionaries or other online reference material

Answer (score 1):

1. Kale - 羽衣甘蓝
2. Water cress - 水田芥；豆瓣菜（别名为西洋菜）
3. Collards/collard greens - 宽叶羽衣甘蓝
4. Brussels sprouts - 球芽甘蓝
5. Leeks - 韭葱
6. Artichokes - 洋蓟

Answer (score 1):

For the nay-sayers who gave the equivalent of "just Google it" - it's actually incredibly helpful to have a comparative list. As an ABC, I speak fluent Chinese but I definitely can't recognize all the veggies and fruits by their Chinese name or vice versa. In fact, I came here looking for all the possible different types of 瓜 while contemplating watermelon since it is "West melon" and was curious if other directional types. I count at least 8 melons that I know the Chinese name of, but searching manually would take a long time and yield sub-par results. Consider yams - you would never consider English to Chinese lookup since they're...tubers and not melons. And this problem is only for the very narrow consideration of "瓜".  The broader category of veggies is even more confusing. And don't get me started on restaurant names.

The "瓜" off the top of my head and their Pinyin are: watermelon (xigua, 西瓜), cantaloupe (hamigua, 哈密瓜), honeydew (tiangua, 甜瓜), yams (digua, 地瓜), wintermelon (donggua, 冬瓜), bittermelon (kugua, 苦瓜), pumpkin (nangua, 南瓜), papaya (mugua, 木瓜)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of finding "official" translations for the words like the ones in your list:

1. go to Wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kale
2. look at "Languages" section bottom left of the page.
3. Locate 中文 - https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%BE%BD%E8%A1%A3%E7%94%98%E8%97%8D
4. Here you go, 羽衣甘藍

Granted, this will quite often give you names used in Taiwan, in traditional characters. Wikipedia is rather dominated by Taiwanese users.

Alternatively, search Baidu eg https://www.google.com.au/search?q=kale+baidu or https://baike.baidu.com/item/Kale

```
英文：kale，中文意思：羽衣甘蓝
```

Baidu is 100% mainland 普通话！

Answer (score 0):

apple banana 苹果蕉

apple mango 苹果芒

apple pear 苹果梨

apple 苹果

apricot 杏

avacado 酪梨，牛油果

banana 香蕉

black plum 黑布霖，黑布冧，黑布林（李子）

blackberry黑莓

blueberry 蓝莓

carambola，starfruit 杨桃

cherry 樱桃

Chinese Date大枣

chufa 荸荠

citrus柑橘

coconut 椰子

cooking banana 大蕉

dateplum persimmon 黑枣

durian 榴梿

egg-fruit，canistel 鸡蛋果，蛋黄果

fig 无花果

grape 葡萄

grapefruit葡萄柚

guava 番石榴，芭乐

Hami cantaloupe，honey-dew melon 哈密瓜

India jujube 印度枣，蜜枣

jackfruit木菠萝，菠萝蜜

juice peach 水蜜桃

lemon，lime，柠檬，莱姆

lichee，litchi 荔枝

longan 龙眼

loquat 枇杷

lycium chinense 枸杞

mandarin orange 橘

mango 芒果

mangosteen 山竹

megranate 石榴

mel，japanese aprocot 梅

mulberry桑椹，桑果

muskmelon，melon 香瓜，甜瓜

mysterious fruit，miracle fruit 神祕果

olive 橄榄

orange 橙子

papaya，pawpaw 木瓜

passion fruit，colombia fruit 西番莲果，百香果，黄仙果

peach 桃子

pear 梨子

persimmon 柿子

pineapple 凤梨、菠萝

pitaya，dragon fruit，pitahaya，night-blooming cereus，strawberry pear 火龙果

plum 李子

ponkan 碰柑

rambutan 红毛丹

red date 红枣

sapodilla 人心果

shaddock 柚子

solamwn muicatnm 人参果

strawberry 草莓

sugar-cane 甘蔗

sweetsop，sugar apple 番荔枝，释迦（像释迦摩尼），梨仔，佛头果

tomato 西红柿

watermelon 西瓜

waxapple，java apple，java rose，rose apple，samarang rose apple，water apple，wax jambu，bell fruit，malay apple， moutain apple，jambu  莲雾（台湾），又名辈雾、琏雾、爪哇蒲桃、洋蒲桃（大陆），水蓊（新加坡和马来西亚）

waxberry 杨梅

wild jujube 酸枣

yellow fruit黄果

干果

almond 杏仁

beechnut 山毛榉

betelnut 槟榔

cashew腰果

chestnut栗子

Chinese Chestnut 板栗

gingko白果，银杏果

ginseng 人参

peanut花生

pine nut 松籽

pistacia vera，pistachio nut开心果，阿月浑子果

pumpkin seeds 南瓜籽

semen nelumbinis 莲米

sesame 芝麻

sunflower seeds 葵花籽

walnut seeds 核桃

water caltrops，water chestnut 菱角

watermelon seeds西瓜籽

蔬菜

a kind of algae which is dark green发菜

a seedling of leguminous plants 豆苗

an annual grass with creeping or upright stems, yellow or gray flowers, hairless pods 赤小豆，红小豆

an edible fungus 木耳

artichoke 洋蓟

asparagus 芦笋

aubergine，eggplant 茄子，茄瓜，矮瓜

baby corn 玉米尖

bamboo  竹笋

bean sprout  豆芽

bean 菜豆

beansprots 绿豆芽

beet，beetroot 甜菜

bitter cucumber苦瓜，凉瓜

broad (英) {或} fava (美) bean 蚕豆

broad bean 蚕豆

broccoli，brocoli 硬花甘蓝（绿色花菜）

broccoliflorets，broccoli 绿花菜

brussels sprouts 芽甘蓝

cabbage 圆白菜，卷心菜，包心菜

caper 刺山柑，老鼠瓜

cardoon 刺菜蓟

carrot 红萝卜，胡萝卜

cauliflower 菜花，花椰菜，白花菜

celery 芹菜，旱芹，唐芹

chayote squash 合掌瓜

chayote 佛手瓜

chervil 雪维菜，细叶芹

chick-pea 鹰嘴豆

chicory 苣荬菜

cilantro香菜 （芫荽的嫩叶）

chillies 辣椒

Chinese cabbage大白菜，绍菜

Chinese chive（Allium tuberosum），garlic chives，Chinese leek韭菜

Chinese leaves 生菜

Chinese watermelon 冬瓜

chive（美国）细香葱

coriander 香菜（干芫荽嫩叶或者芫荽籽实，用作香料）

corn 玉米粒

cos lettuce 莴苣

courgettes 绿皮南瓜（形状似小黄瓜，但不可生食）

cress 水田芥

cucumber 黄瓜

cumin，cummin 孜然芹，枯茗

dandelion 蒲公英

dill 莳萝，俗称小茴香

dioscorea hemsleyi 山药

dwarf bean 四季豆

eddoes 小芋头

enokitake，enoki mushroom，golden needle mushroom，flammulina 金针菇

flat beans 长形平豆

french bean 法国菜豆

garlic 大蒜

gherkin 嫩黄瓜

giantarum 蒟蒻

ginger 姜

green bean 绿豆

green bean 青豆

green pepper 青椒

heart (of a cabbage) 菜心

horseradish 辣根

hot pepper，chilli 辣椒

iceberg 透明包心菜

jerusalem artichoke 洋姜，鬼子姜

kale 无头甘蓝

kohlrabi 甘蓝

laurel 月桂

lentil 兵豆

loofah 丝瓜

lotus root 莲藕

lupin 羽扇豆（美作：lupine）

marrow 嫩葫芦

mushroom 蘑菇，洋菇

mustard  芥菜

mustard & cress 芥菜苗

okra 秋葵

onion 洋葱

oyster mushroom平菇

pakchoi，a variety of Chinese cabbage 小白菜

parsley 欧芹，西芹，荷兰芹

parsnip 欧防风

pea 豌豆

pepper 胡椒

pickled cabbage 雪菜

potato 马铃薯，土豆

purple laver 紫菜

red cabbage 紫色包心菜

red pepper 红椒

salsify 婆罗门参

scallion 葱，青葱

shiitake mushroom，xianggu，lentinus edodes香菇

soya bean，soybean，soy，soya 黄豆

spinach 菠菜

spring onions 葱，小洋葱

sprot 高丽小菜心

straw mushroom 草菇

swede or turnip 芜菁

sweet corn 玉米

sweet pepper，bell pepper，pimiento，capsicum 甜椒, 柿子椒

sweet potato 蕃薯，地瓜（红薯）

taro 芋头

tarragon 狭叶青蒿

thyme 百里香

tomato 番茄，西红柿

tremella 银耳

truffle 块菌

turnip 芜菁

watercress 西洋菜，豆瓣菜

white cabbage 包心菜

wild celery 野芹菜 （水芹菜，water celery） （非中药“独活”）

yellow pepper 黄椒

young (or fresh) soya bean 毛豆

部分北美蔬菜英语单词的更新

kelp大型褐藻（多用于宠物食品）

seaweed海带

purple laver 紫菜

radish小水萝卜，小红（皮）萝卜

white radish白萝卜

mooli 西洋白萝卜

daikon日本萝卜（日语：大根だいこん）

squash南瓜（做菜吃的）

pumpkin南瓜（制糖的或是万圣节玩的）

courgette西葫芦（一说绿皮南瓜）

zucchini西葫芦

vegetable marrow西葫芦

megranate 石榴（果实）

pomegranate石榴（树，或花）

Chinese leaves 生菜叶

romaine lettuce（美国）生菜（叶）

iceberg lettuce卷心莴苣（美国生菜）

cos lettuce 莴苣

dwarf bean 矮生菜豆

green bean四季豆，青豆

coriander 香菜、芫荽

cilantro香菜叶、芫荽叶

fennel（中国）茴香

baby dill / dill（西亚）茴香

green onion（亚洲）细葱

chive （北美）细香葱

scallion青葱，大葱

leek （中东）大葱，韭葱

Chinese chive韭菜

garlic chives韭菜

Chinese leek韭菜

broccoliflorets，broccoli 绿花菜

cauliflower 菜花，花椰菜，白花菜

Chinese broccoli 芥兰菜

sorrel 掌叶大黄

rhubarb大黄（叶柄）

Hongkong names, almost same with main land

1 紹菜、津菜 Tientsin Pakchoi

2 娃娃菜 Mini Tientsin Pakchoi

3 白菜仔 Small Pakchoi

4 小棠菜 Shanghai Pakchoi

5 油麥菜 Indian Lettuce

6 茼蒿  Garland chrysanthemum

7 皇帝菜 Emperor Vegetable

8 唐生菜 Chinese lettuce

9 西生菜 European lettuce

10  意大利生菜 Italian lettuce

11  牛油生菜  Butter Lettuce

12  羅馬生菜  Romina Lettuce

13  沙律生菜  Salad Lettuce

14  芥菜  Leaf mustard

15  芥蘭  Chinese kale

16  菜心  Flowering Chinese cabbage

17  椰菜  Cabbage

18  紅椰菜 Red cabbage

19  西蘭花 Broccoli

20  椰菜花 Cauliflower

21  菠菜  Spinach

22  莧菜  Chinese spinach

23  通菜  Water spinach

24  唐芹  Chinese celery

25  西芹  Celery

26  西洋菜 Watercress

27  豆苗  Pea shoot

28  青毛豆 Green soybean

29  荷蘭豆 Snow pea

30  青豆角 Green string bean

31  蜜糖豆/甜豆  Sugar snap pea

32  四季豆 Kidney bean

33  矮瓜  Eggplant

34  白蘿蔔 Radish

35  青蘿蔔 Green radish

36  甘荀  Carrot

37  珍珠荀 Baby corn

38  粟米鬚 Corn silk

39  沙葛  Yam bean

40  蕃薯  Sweet potato

41  薯仔  Potato

42  芋頭  Taro

43  紅菜頭 Beetroot

44  乾蔥  Dried shallot bulb

45  蒜頭  Garlic bulb

46  薑 Ginger

47  冬瓜  Wax gourd

48  南瓜  Pumpkin

49  西瓜  Water melon

50  佛手瓜 Chayote

51  青瓜  Cucumber

52  絲瓜  Sponge gourd

53  苦瓜  Bitter cucumber

54  節瓜  Hairy gourd

55  葫蘆瓜 Bottle gourd

56  翠玉瓜 Zucchini

57  韮菜花 Bud chives

58  韮菜  Chinese chives

59  枸杞  Chinese wolfberry

60  蔥 Spring onion

61  指天椒 Chili pepper

62  紅尖椒 Red hot pepper

63  青尖椒 Green hot pepper

64  燈籠椒 Sweet pepper

65  番茄  Tomato

66  芫荽  Chinese parsley

67  竹蔗  Sugar cane

68  蘆薈  Aloe

69  香茅  Lemon grass

70  臭草/ 芸香  Common rue

71  木瓜  Papaya

72  洋蔥  Onion

73  薄荷  Mint

74  胡椒薄荷  Pepper Mint

75  檸檬薄荷

76  迷迭香 Rosemary

77  百里香 Thyme

78  芸香（臭草）  Rue

79  芥蘭頭 Kohl Rabi